# Level of Components listening to same redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, apollostack

My situation is as follows:

I have 1 field in my redux state that's nothing more than an object of following type: `{String, [{String, Float}]}`. This field in my state is used by 2 Components (who query over GraphQL using the `String` as a variable).

Both components are connected via the `connect` method (using decorator syntax).

```
@connect((state) => ({variable: state.variable.field}))
@graphql(QUERY, {...})
export default class Component1 extends React.Component { ... }


@connect((state) => ({variable: state.variable.field}))
@graphql(QUERY, {...})
export default class Component2 extends React.Component { ... }
```

Nothing special since this works for every other `Component`. Yet, when I call these components on the same level while logging the state in their `render` methods:

```
<div>
    <Component1 />
    <Component2 />
</div>
```

The `Component1` logs the state as is, `Component2` logs the initial state. When I switch the components in place:

```
<div>
    <Component2 />
    <Component1 />
</div>
```

The opposite happens: `Component2` logs the correct state, `Component1` doesn't.

When I call either one of the components inside each other (where `Component1` calls `Component2` as part of their render), everything is fine.

I'm not sure what is going on here, nor can I find any documentation stating you shouldn't call 2 components listening to the same state on the same location.

Hope someone can help me understand what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this shouldn't be an issue. So maybe the issue is caused by your code? (Just a wild guess w/o seeing any actual code!)

**But** I would suggest to lift the `connect` to Redux into the parent component anyway. Especially if both components require the exact same part of the state.

Comment: I think I got the issue:

The query returned gave an error since the initial state was an empty string, this shouldn't be a problem since the query will fire again when my state changes. But since I didn't explicitly check for an error (just whether or not my state yielded an empty string) I tried accessing an `undefined` value (my so called result). This messed up the internal state causing the component to stop rerendering. 

I'm not sure why the order of the components matter but this is what I got so far.